# Why did I not print out the stack trace when using Logger.error("msg",e)?

Tags: java, exception, logging, stack-trace

1. 

```
try{
   ……
}catch(Exception e){
   ……
   logger.error(String.format("deliverTask error:%s",e.getMessage()),e);
}
```

The log output is

```
deliverTask error:null
```

2. 

```
try{
   ……
}catch(Exception e){
   ……
   logger.error(String.format("deliverTask error:%s",e.toString()),e);
}
```

The log output is

```
deliverTask error:java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Why is this happening? Why are exception details not printed?What do I have to do to get stack trace information?

logging framework:
org.slf4j 1.7.26
logback 1.2.3

Comment: It would help if you clarify which logging framework you're using.

Comment: _"What do I have to do to get stack trace information?"_ using which Logging Framework and API?

Comment: logging framework:   org.slf4j   1.7.26

Comment: slf4j is a façade, and not an implementation.  You're probably using logback as the impl?  Maybe Log4j2?

Comment: logging framework: org.slf4j 1.7.26 logback 1.2.3

Answer (score -1):

I don't see anything wrong with code structure,  I tried similar example, it is printing the exception details.

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class LoggerExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a = 5;
        try{
            a = 5/0;
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.error(String.format("Something went wrong:%s",e.getMessage()),e);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:-

```
main] ERROR test.LoggerExample - Something went wrong:/ by zero
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
    at test.LoggerExample.main(LoggerExample.java:13)
```

You might need to check your logger configuration. I just used lombok where configuration is very simple, you just need to add below snippet in the pom.xml and annotate with @Log or it's variants, I've used  @Slf4j.

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                <version>1.18.24</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
```